# Match inner text between delimiters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex able to find all occurrences of text between a starting and an ending delimiter, which could be potentially any kind of character sequence (though I can accept solutions that don't work with extremely particular combinations of delimiters).

The catch is that I don't want the matched string to contain any occurrence of the delimiters, for example given START and END as delimiters and the following string:

> START match END not matched START tricky one (shouldn't match) START this is good END trailing things

usual approaches would return as matches " match " and " tricky one (shouldn't match) START this is good ", while I need " match " and " this is good " to be matched.

After some (lots of) tries, I was able to produce the following expression, which captures the desired strings in the first group:

> START((?:(?!START).)*?)END

You can try it here https://regex101.com/r/3IOb36/1

What I am worried about is if having the lookaround applied at each character is a too slow approach and if there are more performing solutions which I couldn't find.

Even if there aren't, I still wanted to share my solution since I wasn't able to find another one during my searches.

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: Using a tempered greedy token is correct in these cases, when you need the shortest window between two strings, but it is true this will be slow. You might want to *unroll* this regex. Something like [`START([^SE]*(?:S(?!TART)[^SE]*|E(?!ND)[^SE]*)*)END`](https://regex101.com/r/3IOb36/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew remove the U-modifier from your example ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using php, searching with preg_match_all

Comment: @SebastianProske: It was there because I used the OP fiddle :) Surely it must be removed - https://regex101.com/r/3IOb36/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would your answer work with arbitrary START and END strings? e.g. what happens if they begin with the same character?

Comment: @Leo, unrolling a pattern also depends on what your START and END patterns are. With word boundaries, it is trickier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative look-ahead, e.g. `((?!START).)*`, to search for a string which does not contain `START` and `END` between the two tags.

**Here is an example matching in JavaScript:**

```js
var text = "START match END not matched START tricky one (shouldn't match) START this is good END trailing things";

var regex = /START((?!START)(?!END).)*?END/g;
console.log(text.match(regex));
```